# HTTPSessionListener using Spring injections and Services => impossible to access my beans

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, service, dependency-injection, httpsession

I work on a web app using **Spring annotations** to inject my Controllers and Services. In the app, I have users working on projects but I need to make sure one project is only edited by one user at a time so I have an attribute in the table "Project" in the database to save if the project is open and by whom.

I need to add an HTTPSessionListener to be able to "close" the project when the user editing it disconnects. It means that at the "sessionDestroyed" event, I want to call my DAO service to update the project in the database.
The only problem is that this service is injected by Spring and I cannot get it...

I tried to use @Autowired in my HTTPSessionListener but it didn't work, I tried to do like in this solution ([Spring – How to do dependency injection in your session listener](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-do-dependency-injection-in-your-session-listener/) ) but I get a nullPointerException for the WebApplicationContext...

My web.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<!-- jsp config => automatic inclusions in all jsp files -->
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
        <include-prelude>setLanguage.jsp</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
<display-name>MEANS</display-name>

<!--Spring dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern><!-- detect all urls ending with ".do" -->
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- The welcome files -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>connection.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout><!-- the session is automatically disconnected after 30 min of inactivity -->
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>myPackages.listener.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And the dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- Spring MVC Support for annotations (JSR-303) -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Spring View resolver => find the jsps -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--  Spring info : what packages to scan for detecting annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="myPackages"/>
```

So I need your help... Does anybody have an idea of how I could inject a Spring Service into my HTTPSessionListener?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I updated my post with the web.xml! Thx

Answer (score 3):

One of the options (perhaps the best one from the design point of view) is to create [a bean of scope `session`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session) (don't forget to declare `RequestContextListener`) and put logic associated with the session lifecylce into it. Spring will automatically call its destruction method (annotated with `@PreDestroy` or configured as `destroy-method`) when session is to be destroyed.

Your approach with injection into session listener causes problems because you only have `DispatcherServlet`, not `ContextLoaderListener`, and `WebApplicationContextUtils` cannot obtain an application context associated with `DispatcherServlet`. If you choose to follow that apporach you should create a root application context and extract some of your beans into it, then you will be able to access it from session listener via `WebApplicationContextUtils`.

Comment: Do you have a complete example of how your describe solution would be achieved? I have this same problem. Yet I also tried using WebApplicationContextUtils for my bean lookup and still no luck. Thanks in advance